# Apache2 htaccess redirection too many redirects

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create an apache2 .htaccess redirection. I want to redirect this:

**http://www.mywebsite.com/category/books  to http://www.mywebsite.com/category/books/?fwp_categories=books**

I have tried to do this, but i am getting a '**too many redirects**' error:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/category/$1?fwp_categories=$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `RewriteCond` before this rule to prevent adding query parameter when it is already there:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)fwp_categories= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(category)/(.*?)/?$ /$1/$2?fwp_categories=$2 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

Comment: Mmm OK, but if i go to http://www.mywebsite.com/category/books/ with final slash, you rule is redirecting me to http://www.mywebsite.com/category/books/?fwp_categories=books%2F and the %2F is throwing me an error in my WP.